# Inserted iframes are not cleared from the DOM with GTM

Tags: google-analytics, dom-events, analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have a GTM script implemented in my Angular application (SPA - Single Page Application).

When I change the page, a Page-View event is triggered via: `window.dataLayer.push(obj)`

**obj** represents the whole object.

On GTM side, I have 2 triggers as a result:

1. Insert to the DOM a Custom HTML element (a script element) that triggers another dataLayer.push with a simple object that indicates the new page view and the previous referer.
2. Insert to the DOM an iframe of type DoubleClick Floodlight to track certain behaviors for a short lifespan.

Now, to my understanding, these events should have been inserted to the DOM once and get cleared after that.

As it seems, for every page view that a user creates while navigating in the app, linearly, 2 elements are appended to the DOM (scropt element + iframe).

This behavior causes a tremendous amount of js heap size. I see a great memory leak in the Memory tab in chrome DevTools.

Of course, dataLayer keeps track of events and once it gets to 300 events it pops the oldest event, etc...

I would like to know is this is an expected behavior by design and it's just me that is missing a key component in GTM.

Am I supposed to create a cleanup tag to trigger after all of my elements are inserted to the DOM?

Or even better, try to track it and remove it from within my application?

I feel like I did not truly understand my problem so I can only hope you have a clue what I'm aiming to explain here.

Thanks ahead.

I did not try anything.

All I did was to read stackoverflow questions and answers, combined with a lot of articles, videos, dry documentation.

I do have a few leads as to what to try and tackle but I prefer the community to guide me through their experience if possible.

Comment: That is alas the expected behaviour. I asked the same thing shortly after GTM was introduced. I know of no solution, only hacky workarounds like using a cleanup script via a tag sequence. Also I do not understand the close votes, this seems like a perfectly fine question.